# not launching the splash screen correctly in all iPhone in xcode

Tags: ios

I need to display the splash screen .So in the `Assests.xcassests` file I created a new launch image and I set the image in:-

```
iPhone portrait ios 5,6:-
1x-320*480
2x-640*960
Retina 4-640*1136

iPhone portait ios 8,9:-
RetinaHD 5.5-1242*2208
Retaina HD4.7-750*1334

iPhone portrait ios 7-9:-
2x-640*960
Retina 4-640*1136
```

This are the sizes I given .And I run at each simulator.
In iPhone 5,6,6 plus,7,SE:-   Working

But iPhone 7 plus,6s plus,6s - not in correct size

And iPhone 5s- not displaying the image

How to resolve this problem

Comment: I would strongly suggest you use a launch storyboard so that autolayout can adapt the scene to the device.

Comment: @Paulw11 but what size i need to give for universal

Comment: You need to make an image that is larger than iPhone X resolution and let autolayout scale it down and crop it as required.

Answer (score 0):

Add image in Assests with 1024x1024 size then It will work. No need to take 1x,2x,3x.

--
Hope this will help you.

Comment: i have already created a new launch screen in assets....then how to set

Comment: Simple Go to your launch screen option in Xcode. Take an UIImageView set it's constraints and fill the image With 1024x1024 size.